# Aren't All Bases Othonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra

It's probably a very stupid question, but someone isn't all basis orthonormal ? For example, let $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}$. Of course $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. But in $\mathbb R^2=Span\{v_1,v_2\}$, we have that $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$. So with respect to the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$, the family $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is orthonormal, no ? I'm a bit confuse now... If yes, Gramm-schmidt is useless so I guess something is wrong in what I'm saying. Could someone enlighten me ?

Comment: Basis can be orthonormal with respect to different dot products, but not all basis are orthonormal with respect to a fixed dot product.

Comment: Have you read this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727220/non-orthonormal-basis-vectors-impossible  ?

Comment: There are many possible inner products on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If you have any basis, you can define an inner product such that that basis is orthonormal.  When people refer to a basis as orthonormal, they must specify, implicitly or explicitly, a particular inner product - usually the standard dot product.  Your basis is not orthonormal with respect to the standard dot product.

Comment: @JairTaylor: Yes it is orthonormal (with standard inner product) since $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=0\cdot 1+1\cdot 0=0.$

Comment: @user657324 I meant that $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is not orthonormal (with respect to the dot product.)

Comment: @JairTaylor: How can it not be since in $\{v_1,v_2\}$ in $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is nothing else tha $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. So it is orthonormal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just switch bases and expect the dot product to compute the same thing, as your example shows. The coordinate representation of the inner product has to change away from the dot product to something else.

The dot product's Gram matrix reads $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ but after the change of basis which converts from these coordinates to coordinates of the second basis you gave, the new Gram matrix is

$\begin{bmatrix}4&8\\8&20\end{bmatrix}$, thus the inner product, computed both with the old and new coordinates matches:

$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4&8\\8&20\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=8$.

The mistake you were making was thinking that the Gram matrix stayed the same between the two expressions, but it *does* change.

And what about the original basis?

Well $[1,0]$ was sent to $[1/2, 0]$ and $[0,1]$ was sent to $[-1, 1/2]$, and

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4&8\\8&20\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1/2\end{bmatrix}=0$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4&8\\8&20\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\0\end{bmatrix}=1$

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1/2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4&8\\8&20\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1/2\end{bmatrix}=1$

so it is still orthonormal.

**Remember**: *Inner products have an existence outside of coordinates, and the dot product depends on a basis.* We pick a basis and switch to coordinates to do computation sometimes, but choice of basis is immaterial, and won't affect the end result that the inner product computes.  So, changing the basis out from under the inner product changes the way the quantity is computed.

The same goes for linear transformations and the matrices we choose to represent them.

To give an example of a similar mistake you could try with transformations:

> "$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is in the kernel of the linear transformation $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$, but when I use $v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ in a basis so that $v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ it is not in the kernel anymore... why?"

The answer is, of course, that the matrix has to change when the basis changes too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just saw on wikipedia what is Gram matrix, and in $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is given by $G_{ij}=(\left<v_{i},v_j\right>)_{ij}$. So in my case, it should be $G_{ij}=\delta _{ij}$ and thus $v_iG_{ij}v_j=(0,1)^TI_2(0,1)=\delta _{ij}$ where $I_2$ is the identity matrix $2\times 2$... so at the end, $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is orthonormal in $\{v_1,v_2\}$. (I'm sure you right at the end, but I can't convince my self for the moment...)

Comment: Yes, the Gram matrix for the dot product with respect to *any* basis is the identity matrix. But it still seems the point is escaping you: the dot product is not invariant when you change basis.  *Every* inner product on $\mathbb R^2$ looks like the dot product in some basis. They are not all the same inner product!  Your mistaken expectation that the dot product has to remain the same after a change of basis seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A "vector space", in the general "Linear Algebra" sense, does not have an inner product attached and that is what is needed for "orthogonality".

In any finite dimensional space, given a basis $\{v_1, v_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot, v_n\}$, we can define "standard" inner product: If $u= a_1v_1+ a_2v_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_nv_n$ and $v= b_1v_1+ b_2v_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ b_nv_n$ then the "standard" inner product is $a_1b_1+ a_2b_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_nb_n$.

The "usual basis" for $R^2$ is {<1, 0>, <0, 1>} but any two independent vectors will form a basis.  For example, {<1, 0>, <1, 1>} is a perfectly good basis and the vectors <1, 0>, <1, 1> are not "orthogonal" with the "standard" definition of inner product which then gives the usual definiton of "angle"- they have angle 45 degrees.

However, given any basis for a vector space it is always possible to **redefine** the inner product so that the basis vectors are orthogonal.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The basis is orthonormal respect to a inner product $\cdot$ if

1. $|v_i|=1,\forall i$
2. $v_i\cdot v_j=0,\forall i\neq j$

The vectors of the basis you showed do not have norm equal to 1, and if we use the common inner product you have that $v_1\cdot v_2 = 8\neq 0$, so it is not orthonormal.